# Вывести значение 2го элемента бд

Tags: php, mysql

Ребят привет! Нужна помощь, если 2 словах есть товар - он находиться в 2 категориях!
В БД выглядит так - первый столбец - ид товара - 2 ид категорий куда он 
прикреплен!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот пишу код:

```
$dad_result = mysql_query("select * from oc_product_to_category where (product_id = 99)") or die(mysql_error());
        $oc_product_to_category = mysql_fetch_array($dad_result);
echo $oc_product_to_category['category_id'];
```

и выводит только первое значение, а нужно именно второе!

Подскажите что делаю не так!

Comment: не очень понятно, что такое второе значение, если вы никак не упорядочиваете ответ

Comment: в бд нет "первого (или второго) значения", в бд есть "первое (или второе, третье и т.д.) значение, в полученном наборе", т.е. выполнив два раз один и тот же запрос можно получить совсем другой набор данных и, как следствие, второе значение каждый раз будет разным. Поэтому необходимо знать как отличить "первое" от "второго". Чаще всего для задания определенного порядка используют сортировку по определенному полю, тогда (за редким исключением) уже можно на каждый запрос получить ожидаемый результат (т.е. те же данные для нескольких одинаковых запросов)

Comment: @BOPOH да, вы не ленивы, сэр :) меня хватило только на 10 слов :)))

Comment: спасибо ребят буду пробовать!

Comment: @splash58 ну так это и не ответ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Программа, отработала так, как Вы и просили, вывела значение. Если бы вы использовали цикл, то получили бы все значения:

```
while ($oc_product_to_category = mysql_fetch_array($dad_result)) {
    echo $oc_product_to_category['category_id'];
}
```

Так же, для получения, конкретно 2го значения, можно использовать [mysql_result](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-result.php):

```
echo mysql_result($oc_product_to_category, 1, 1);
```

Comment: а как получить именно второе значение?

Comment: @lxxnutsxxl подправил